# Looping through multiple types of inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write some form validation in jQuery. It's basic, I'm only checking for empty inputs.

However, there are three different types of elements on my form: `<input type="text">`, `<select>` and `<input type="checkbox">`. I'm having troubles getting my validation working with all of these.

This is my code so far:

**Partial-HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" name="required" value="title,first_name,family_name,job_title,company_name,country,address_1,town_city,post_code,telephone_2,email,subprimary_activity,subjob_title2,subscription" />
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("input[name=submit_form]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var missing_items = [];
    var required_array = $("input[name=required]").val().split(",");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < required_array.length; i++) {
        var input_name = required_array[i];
        if ($("input[name=" + input_name + "]").val() == "" || $("select[name=" + input_name + "]").val() == "" || !$("input[name=" + input_name + "]").is(":checked")) {
            missing_items.push(input_name);
        }
    }
    alert(missing_items);
});
```

The `alert()` currently notifies me of every element, whether or not it's missing a value/check. I know this why this is - it's because my `if` has three parameters, and as something can't be an `<input>` *and* a `<select>`, it will always evaluate true.

How can I rewrite this so that is functions correctly? Is there a way of checking what *type* of input an element is, or if a specific element *exists* and therefore only running the relevant validaton?

e.g.

```
if (is input text) {
    check val() ! empty
}
else if (is select) {
    check val() !empty
}
else if (is input checkbox) {
    check :checked
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code here

```
if ($("input[name=" + input_name + "]").val() == "" || $("select[name=" + input_name + "]").val() == "" || !$("input[name=" + input_name + "]").is(":checked")) {
            missing_items.push(input_name);
        }
```

To this

```
var element = $("[name=" + input_name + "]");
if(element.is(":text"))
  // your code
else if (element.is("select")
  // your code
else if (element.is(":checkbox")
  // your code
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I'll go for something like this :

(fake code, take a look at the [doc selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) and [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) )

```
$("input[type=text]").each(
    check val() ! empty
)
$("select").each(
    check val() !empty
)
$("input[type=checkbox]").each(
    check :checked
)
```

Here a code sample for the `text` fields

```js
function f() {
  $("input[type=text]").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="hello">
<br>
<input type="email" value="test@test.com">
<br>
<input type="text" value="hola">
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="f()" value="run">
<br>
```

Comment: Would I work this inside my `for` loop, or work my `for` loop inside each `.each()`?

Comment: `each()` is already a loop like your `for`, so take a look at the doc, it's really worth it for what you want I think ; first you select all field of one type with the JQuery selector, and the each() loop on each one of it, so you can make your check inside

Comment: @mpdc I put the wrong link of the doc, so edit ; + add a sample of how it work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did:

```
$("input[name=submit_form]").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var missing_items = [];
    var $requiredInputs = $("input.required, select.required");

    $requiredInputs.each( function () {
      if ($(this).attr("type") == 'text' && $(this).val().length <= 0) {
        missing_items.push($(this));
      }
        if ($(this).attr("type") == 'checkbox' && !$(this).is(":checked")) {
        missing_items.push($(this));
      }
        if ($(this).is('select') && $(this).val().length <= 0) {
        missing_items.push($(this));
      }
    });

    alert(missing_items);
});
```

And here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s9hd7jjq/2/

A slightly modified version of your code. I'm grabbing all inputs and selects with a class of required on them. Then I loop through each one using the .each method, first checking it's type, then a second conditional whether is populated or checked etc. If it isn't, its pushed into your missing items array.

You could easily change this to check if the element is empty by changing each conditional. I think it should set you on the right path though.

Answer (score 0):

You can check input is text type or not using following method :-

```
if( $(this).is('input') ) // $(this) is your form element
{ 
    // it was an input
}
```

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the type of input by checking its type attribute

```
function validate( $input )
{
   if ( $input.attr( "type" ) == 'text' && $input.val().length > 0 ) return true;
   if ( $input.attr( "checkbox" ) == 'text' && $input.is(":checked") ) return true;
   if ( $input.prop("tagName") == 'select'&& $input.val().length > 0 ) return true;
  return false;
}
```